# Is the Rails default CSRF protection insecure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, xss, csrf

By default the form post CSRF protection in Rails creates an authenticity token for a user that only changes when the user's session changes. One of our customers did a security audit of our site and flagged that as an issue.

The auditor's statement was that if we also had a XSS vulnerability that an attacker could grab another user's authenticity token and make use of it for CSRF attacks until the user's session expired.

But is seems to me that if we had an XSS vulnerability like that an attacker could just as easily grab another user's session cookie and login as that user directly. Or even just make calls to our REST Api from script as the user being attacked. Being able to mount a CSRF attack doesn't seem any worse in such a situation... the problem would be the XSS vulnerability.

Have I missed something? Is there a real problem with the default CSRF protection in Rails?

Comment: Please note a vulnerability in CSRF for Rails was discovered and exists in Rails version 3.0.3 and below. See http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/2/8/csrf-protection-bypass-in-ruby-on-rails. Upgrade to 3.0.4 to ensure this issue is addressed.

Comment: As a side note, session cookies should be set to `HttpOnly` so they can't be stolen by XSS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are entirely correct.  Token based CSRF protection is the most common and as long as you test your application for XSS you should be fine.

There are cases where CSRF can still be stopped regardless of XSS.   For instance,  for your password change forum,  require that they know the current password. A hacker will be unable to forge this request unless he knows the current password, a moot point.

Another method is to require a Captcha to be solve for that request.   I recommend using reCapthca.

Comment: Technically, if you have a form that requires an user inputted password in addition to other data, you're not protecting from CSRF or XSS but stolen sessions. CSRF attack is about being able to execute commands on another site using credentials of current browser session.

Comment: Notice that if you have an XSS vulnerability and a form that requires user to enter non-OTP password, the attacker just got the user's password!

Comment: @Mikko Rantalainen that would be phishing,  not CSRF.  You could use xss to rewrite the body of the page into a forum that accepts a password.  But if there is form asking for a password on some other page,  then XSS can't be used to read that password because it cannot be read with an XHR.

Comment: you are right that XSS vulnerability on a page that asks for user's password is required to get the password without phishing. In addition, if you have login form embedded on every page of the site (as usual nowadays), any XSS vulnerability can lead to exposed user passwords (use XSS to silently submit the stolen login/password somewhere else using XHR).

Comment: @Mikko Rantalainen rewrite the onsubmit handler to transmit the username/password to the attacker's servers.

Comment: I think we're on the same page. I would like to add that much more effective XSS attack would submit copy of login/password data to 3rd party. That way the attack would have much better change going undetected.